# Where does the value of the variable come from?

Tags: javascript

There is a very large JS code, it has functions and data that I need to repeat, but I can not find it. [JS-script](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2sfdvmn0u2ngusf/test.js).

It has a function for sending data:

```js
yield n.post("/analysis/keys", {
    version: "v2",
    keys: t
})
```

I just can not find where the data in the variable `t` (keys) comes from?

Comment: Your IDE/editor should have the capability of finding the declaration of a variable in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t` is the second parameter of this generator function: `function*(e, t) {` defined some lines before. That function is passed as parameter to the `l` function, defined as follows:

```
function l(e) {
    return function() {
        var t = e.apply(this, arguments);
        return new Promise(function(e, n) {
            return function r(i, o) {
                try {
                    var a = t[i](o),
                        s = a.value
                } catch (e) {
                    return void n(e)
                }
                if (!a.done) return Promise.resolve(s).then(function(e) {
                    r("next", e)
                }, function(e) {
                    r("throw", e)
                });
                e(s)
            }("next")
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Top of the javascript code, if you see very closely.

```
! function(e) {
    var t = {};
```

[image]

`t` is a js object.

Comment: Yes, but many of them are actually inside another function, either as parameter or local variable of that particular function. In this case the function `l(e, t)` has parameter `t`, so, your post method is actually using the `t` coming as function parameter.